# Well-/Ill-posedness of finding the value of integral of a function in $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

From an old exam problem set :

> Given $f \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$, find $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx$.
>
> > The task is to check if the above problem is :
> >
> > > a) Well-posed/ill-posed if $\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$ is used on $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$, **and**
> > >       b) Well-posed/ill-posed if $\|\cdot\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}$ is used on $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$.

=> **My intuition :** I have a feeling that it is well-posed when $\|\cdot\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R})}$ is used and ill-posed when $\|\cdot\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}$ is used. I think somehow the continuous dependence will be the deciding factor. But I have no clue how to make my intuition rigorous (if the intuition is true at all). So, any proof / counter-example will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exact definition of "well posed"?

Comment: Also, your title is about finding a function, but the problem in your question is about finding a real number (and looks rather strange).  Are you sure you have copied it correctly?

Comment: Hello Nate, edited the title. The problem was copied correctly. I guess it is the standard task of checking existence - uniqueness - continuous dependence. That's why Ientioned I am really clueless about the continuous dependence part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuous dependence, I presume you are asking when the map:
$$ T : C^{\infty}_0(\Bbb R) \rightarrow \Bbb R $$
defined by sending
$$ f \mapsto\int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $$
is continuous with respect to the given norm. Here I'm assuming $C^{\infty}_0(\Bbb R) = C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb R) = $ compactly supported smooth functions to ensure the above is well-defined.

Since the above mapping is linear, it is bounded as a map $(C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb R),\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R)}) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ if and only if there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$ |Tf|  = \left| \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \right| \leq C \lVert f \rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R)} $$
for all $f \in C_0^{\infty}(\Bbb R).$

So for both case when $p=1$ and $p=\infty,$ you need to show that either such a $C$ exists independently of $f$ (dependence is continuous), or exhibit a sequence of $f_k \in C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb R)$ demonstrating that no such $C>0$ exists (problem is ill-posed). I assume you can take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot @ktoi. Yes considering any mollifier with the maximum value less than $1$ should do the job. Total integral being equal to $1$, where as the supremum is less than $1$. Isn't that right?

Comment: @user92360 Are you considering the $p=1$ case of the $p=\infty$ case? I don't understand what your construction is, but it sounds like your inequality is the wrong way around. If you wish to show ill-posedness in the $p=\infty$ case, you could construct for instance a family $f_k$ such that $|Tf_k| > k \lVert f_k \rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Bbb R)}$ for all $k.$

Comment: For the sake of clarity, can you give me an example of such a "family $f_{k}$ such that $|Tf_{k}|>k∥f_{k}∥_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})} \forall $k$" ? I think I am misunderstanding something here. Sorry for being this late. The COVID is taking its toll.

Comment: What I had in my mind, the smooth mollified modification of the following function
$f_{k}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, x \in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \\ 0, x \in (-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{k}) \cup (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{k},\infty)\end{cases}$. 

But, this preccisely doesn't satisfy the desired inequality, isn't it?

Comment: @user92360 Consider for instance $f_k(x) = \chi_{(-k,k)}(x),$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A.$ Then if $\varphi$ is a standard mollifier $g_k = f_k \ast \varphi$ satisfies $|Tg_k| \approx 2k$ while  $\lVert g_k \rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Bbb R)} = 1.$

Comment: Ahh haa... yuup... now, got it... Thanks a lot..